# How can one obtain true sans serif for the numeral 1?

Tags: sans-serif

For the numeral 1, neither `\textsf` nor `\mathsf` provide true sans serif; there is always a pedestal. How can 1 be typeset in true sans serif?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Raymond Sounds to me like you don't like the font design in CM: the 'pedestal' at the base of the 1 isn't a serif, so this is a design choice.

Comment: tex never draws the character shapes. `\textsf` selects whichever font has been specified as the sans serif font. (You haven't given many clues about which fonts you are using.) the shape of the glyphs is then under control of the font designer. From TeX you can select different sans serif fonts.

Answer (score 4):

Whether or not a sans-serif font features a "pedestal" for the numeral `1` is a design choice. The presence or absence of a pedestal does *not* make it a correct or incorrect sans-serif font.

Here are three examples each of sans serif fonts with and without a pedestal. I make no claim as to how representative these examples are, and I have no view as to which form may be "better".

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example
\begin{document}
Some sans-serif fonts \emph{with} a ``pedestal'' for the numeral 1:

\smallskip
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Sans} 1 Latin Modern Sans \\
\setmainfont{Calibri} 1 Calibri\\
\setmainfont{Comic Sans MS} 1 Comic Sans MS

\bigskip
\rmfamily
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
Some sans-serif fonts \emph{without} such a pedestal:

\smallskip
\setmainfont{Helvetica Neue} 1 Helvetica Neue\\
\setmainfont{Myriad Pro} 1 Myriad Pro\\
\setmainfont{Palatino Sans Com Regular} 1 Palatino Sans Com Regular
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the font used, not only on the `\mathsf` etc. command. If the font is a `serif` font, it does not provide *sans serif* style of the font of course. A sans serif (grotesque) font which does not have the 'pedestial', for example, is the standard Helvetica. I try to figure out more of those fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}

\begin{document}
Textfont, serif: 1

Textfont, sans serif: \textsf{1}%

Math font, still serif: \(\mathsf{1}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There are sans-serif fonts with and without a "pedestal", as the OP calls it, for the numeral `1`. `Computer Modern Sans Serif` happens to provide a "pedestal" (and `Calibri` has an even more pronounced pedestal), whereas `Helvetica` does not.

Comment: @Mico: I know, but I was in a hurry and usually just use Helvetica only, so I can't remember which sans serif fonts have `1` with a pedestials. I will clearify my statement in my example

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Cabin`, that looks fine with `fourier` (which can be complemented by `heuristica` or `erewhon`) if scaled. It exists in bold and semibold versions, and has true  smallcaps and italic smallcaps.

The following code also defines it as the math sans font, adding a semibold version:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[scaled = 0.91]{cabin}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand\sbseries{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}
\newcommand\textsb[1]{{\sbseries#1}}

\DeclareMathVersion{semibold}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{T1}{Cabin-TLF}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet\mathsf{normal}{T1}{Cabin-TLF}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet\mathsf{bold}{T1}{Cabin-TLF}{b}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet\mathsf{semibold}{T1}{Cabin-TLF}{sb}{n}
\newcommand\sboldmath{\mathversion{semibold}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

This is a ‘true’ one: \textsf{1.1011011101111…}\vskip1cm

 \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\qquad}>{\sffamily}l@{\qquad}l}
  Cabin Regular & 1234567890 & $ \mathsf{e = 2.718 \dots} $ \\
Cabin Bold: & \textbf{1234567890} & \boldmath $ \mathsf{e = 2.718 \dots} $ \\
Cabin Semibold: & \textsb{1234567890} & \sboldmath $ \mathsf{e = 2.718 \dots} $
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]